# ESTA State/Province/Region required but there is no sensible answer

Tags: usa, esta

I'm filling out an ESTA for travel the the US later this year. I've done this before but they've recently added several new fields, including address in home country. Iceland in my case.

The problem is that one of the address fields is 'state/province/region', but there is no valid answer for this in an Icelandic address. We simply do not have any level between municipal and country-wide.

To be clear, I'm not asking for supposition on what I *might* enter there, please only answers with links to US government sites.

[image]

Comment: You have no states or provinces, but what about areas, like Höfuðborgarsvæði?

Comment: Ie - [Regions in Iceland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Iceland) (not part of my answer as I'm uncertain if these are official)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Just repeat the most appropriate field**, in your case country.  When I lived in Singapore, which as a city-state has [*no* divisions whatsoever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_Singapore), my addresses in forms always looked like this:

> - City: Singapore
> - State: Singapore
> - Country: Singapore

And I never had the slightest problem.

Comment: This is what I did and the application went through.

Answer (score 3):

You state that there's no levels between municipality and country - eg state, province, region.

However, [the ESTA form](https://www.esta-america.org/esta-application.html) specifically mentions another one:

> " * State/province/region/municipality "

and in the "more information" part on this field:

> In the “state/province/region/municipality etc.” field, enter the
>   state, province, region or municipality that you live in (the term
>   used to describe the region you live in might vary depending on which
>   country you live in).

So even if you have no state, province, or region - as you mentioned, you do have a municipality, so can enter that.

Comment: Hmm, this is not the same URL that the airline sent me to (https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov) It seems non-official. I've update my question with a screenshot.